# How to optimize an image with CLIP loss using Pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch

I have some text "banana" and I'm trying to optimize an image with respect to CLIP loss.

However, all I see with this code is a noise image. It seems like pure white noise. I suspect I have done a mistake in the image representation.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
from PIL import Image
from IPython.display import display
from torchvision.transforms import ToPILImage
import numpy as np

import clip  # OpenAI clip

device = "cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"
model, preprocess = clip.load("ViT-B/32", device=device)
input_image = torch.randn(1, 3, 224, 224, requires_grad=True, device=device)
target_text = "banana"

optimizer = optim.Adam([input_image], lr=5e-3)

for i in range(2000):
    image_features = model.encode_image(input_image)
    text_features = model.encode_text(clip.tokenize(target_text).to(device))
    loss = -1 * (image_features * text_features).sum()
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()

    print(f'Iteration {i}: Loss: {loss.item()}')


# Display
output_image = ((input_image) + 1) / 2
image_array = output_image.detach().cpu().squeeze().numpy()
image_array = image_array.transpose(1, 2, 0)
pil_image = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(image_array * 255))
display(pil_image)
```

Comment: I think minimizing feature distance does not guarantee the input image to become a banana. Can you provide some reference for this idea?

Comment: Inspired from Text2Mesh

Comment: You are only displaying the random pixels you started with. Besides, I don't think this would ever work as the CLIP model is not finetune-friendly (unless you have a lot of data)

Comment: @Josmy How am I only displaying the pixels I started with?

Comment: I roughly take a look in Text2Mesh paper, thanks for a new idea. How about starting from more simplified task like transferring a yellow banana to a green one, not from fully generating the object from noise?

Comment: Also normalizing `image_features` and `text_features` seems to be helpful (constructing cosine distance)

Comment: Check the range of values on the image after optimization. You need to keep values between [0,1] for conversion to an image to work